# J2EE/Java Spring and Reactjs - how to build

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-mvc, webpack

I am working on a reactjs build - and the backend api service will be powered by a Java spring MVC. How do I perform the build so integration is smooth -- avoiding any cross domain issues, where does the reactjs app folder go, how do I go about configuring the webpack accordingly or building a fabric script etc..

Comment: _please share stories/links/tutorials

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/